# How to achieve having three 33.333% width DIV elements on the same line while having 10px margin-right on first and second one?

Tags: html, css

If I add margin-right: 10px on the first and second child and 0px on the third child, my third child goes to a new line.

I completely understand that the 2x10px margin-right is causing this but I don't know how to avoid it.

```css
.albums-container {
    font-size: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.albums-container-element {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    width: 33.33333%;
}
.albums-container-element:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.centeredImage {  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="albums-container">

    <div class="albums-container-element">
        <img class='centeredImage' src='https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/4j55UCCc_TyTHtgwflSG8TeGpBU=/960x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg'>
    </div>
    
    <div class="albums-container-element">
        <img class='centeredImage' src='https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/4j55UCCc_TyTHtgwflSG8TeGpBU=/960x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg'>
    </div>
    
    <div class="albums-container-element">
        <img class='centeredImage' src='https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/4j55UCCc_TyTHtgwflSG8TeGpBU=/960x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg'>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

Using the **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** function, which allows you to do mathematical calculations with CSS. In this case, you're looking for `calc(33.333% - 6.666px)`, along with `margin-right: 10px` applied only to the first two elements:

```css
.albums-container {
  font-size: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.albums-container-element {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(33.333% - 6.666px);
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.albums-container-element:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.centeredImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="albums-container">

  <div class="albums-container-element">
    <img class='centeredImage' src='https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/4j55UCCc_TyTHtgwflSG8TeGpBU=/960x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg'>
  </div>

  <div class="albums-container-element">
    <img class='centeredImage' src='https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/4j55UCCc_TyTHtgwflSG8TeGpBU=/960x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg'>
  </div>

  <div class="albums-container-element">
    <img class='centeredImage' src='https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/4j55UCCc_TyTHtgwflSG8TeGpBU=/960x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg'>
  </div>

</div>
```

Or using the **[CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)**, which would mean you would only need the following rules on the container (with **no** rules needed on the children):

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
grid-column-gap: 10px;
```

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.albums-container {
  font-size: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.centeredImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="albums-container">

  <div class="albums-container-element">
    <img class='centeredImage' src='https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/4j55UCCc_TyTHtgwflSG8TeGpBU=/960x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg'>
  </div>

  <div class="albums-container-element">
    <img class='centeredImage' src='https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/4j55UCCc_TyTHtgwflSG8TeGpBU=/960x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg'>
  </div>

  <div class="albums-container-element">
    <img class='centeredImage' src='https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/4j55UCCc_TyTHtgwflSG8TeGpBU=/960x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg'>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flex:

```css
.albums-container {
    font-size: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    
    display:flex;
    
}

.albums-container-element:nth-child(2n) {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.centeredImage {  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="albums-container">

    <div class="albums-container-element">
        <img class='centeredImage' src='https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/4j55UCCc_TyTHtgwflSG8TeGpBU=/960x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg'>
    </div>
    
    <div class="albums-container-element">
        <img class='centeredImage' src='https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/4j55UCCc_TyTHtgwflSG8TeGpBU=/960x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg'>
    </div>
    
    <div class="albums-container-element">
        <img class='centeredImage' src='https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/4j55UCCc_TyTHtgwflSG8TeGpBU=/960x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg'>
    </div>
    
</div>
```